# java program compiles with no error but does not run

Tags: java

Here is my code after changes suggested by stackoverflow members. The code compiles with no errors but when I run "java Realtor11", I get the following errors. I am importing the correct libraries so not sure what the issue is.

The goal of the program is to read two values (first line is a string (John) and the second line is a double (100)) and output them with some calculations to a JOption message.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException 
>           at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
>           at Realtor11.main(Realtor11.java:49)

```
// java class for keyboard I/O
import java.util.Scanner;
// java class for JOption GUI
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
// File reader
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class Realtor11
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    // Keyboard and file input
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in); 
        Scanner inputStream = null;
    // price of the house, the cost to sell the house and the commission
        double price = 0;
        double cost, commission;
    // seller's name
        String seller = "name";



// GUI diplay message declaration
    String display_message = "This program calculates the cost to sell a home\n" 
    + "and the commission paid to an individual sales agent.\n\n"
    + "The user is asked for the last name of the seller and the\n"
    + "sales price.\n\n";

// Output descriptive messages
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, display_message, "Lab 1 Description", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

// Read Realtor11.txt
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Realtor11.txt"));
        while (in.read()!= -1);
        seller = in.readLine();
        price = Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
        in.close();
        } 

        catch (IOException e) {}


// calculate the cost and the commission
    cost = 0.06 * price;
    commission = 0.015 * price;
// display the input and results
    String 
        out1 = String.format("%nThe " + seller + "'s" + " home sold for $%.2f%n", price),
        out2 = String.format("The cost to sell the home was $%.2f%n", cost),
        out3 = String.format("The selling or listing agent earned $%.2f%n", commission);

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, out1 + out2 + out3, seller + "'s Home Sale", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

// Output to file
// still writing this. 

}
```

}

Comment: What's at the line the error points to?

Comment: Time to do a little debugging. Consider using a debugger or sprinkle your code with lots of printlns.

Comment: Just FYI - I explicitly declare variables 'price' and 'seller' since I was getting compile errors. But I assume that should not matter since the variables would bu updated based on the contents of the text file.

Comment: A NullPointerException is thrown when an application attempts to use null in a case where an object is required: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html As @HovercraftFullOfEels suggested you should debug your application.

Comment: isn't the error self-explaining? you know the error, you know the line number and you can check what causes this type of error. try debugging.

Comment: The last error is line 49 based on the terminal. The other 2 do not have line numbers. Again, when I type javac Realtor11.java there are no compile errors. But when I type java Realtor the above error shows up.

Comment: show us what Realtor11.txt looks like?

Comment: Yes. there are runtime errors.

Comment: Wadaya mean it didn't run??  It ran all the way to line 49!

Comment: @HotLicks ha yeah it did ! I wish it ran all the way without errors and opened the JOption message.

Comment: @LoganMurphy First line is John Second line is 100

Comment: There are times when you're glad to even get an error message out of a program.

Comment: @alex Sorry but I am very new to this and believe me - I have been researching all day. I guess with practice I will eventually figure things out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These three lines cause the error:

```
    while (in.read()!= -1);           // this reads until EOF
    seller = in.readLine();           // this gets a null-pointer since we're behind EOF
    price = Double.parseDouble(in.readLine()); // same as above, This is the printed error.
```

That should probably be:

```
    seller = in.readLine();  // first line: seller
    price = Double.parseDouble(in.readLine()); // second line: price
```

This can be improved:

```
    seller = in.readLine();  // first line: seller
    String sPrice = in.readLine(); // second line: price
    if ( sPrice != null )
        price = Double.parseDouble(sPrice);
```

Comment: Thank you Axel for EOF statement. Now I understand why the values would not process after the first line.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this line.

```
while (in.read()!= -1);
```

This is kind of a "degenerate loop" because of the semicolon at the end.  It continues to read from the file until there's nothing left to be read.  After that, there are no `double` values to parse.

Comment: True and I fixed this. Still the same error. I am working through the other comments. I am new to this so will keep researching.

Comment: Good eye David. I wouldn't have recognised that.

Comment: OK, how did you fix it?  What is your call to `Double.parseDouble` seeing now?  It's a bit hard to debug partially-fixed code, without seeing what the fix is.

Comment: Guess you just deleted the ; which means he reads "sellers" until the EOF and the Double.parseDouble still gets a null because of EOF already reached ...

Comment: Yes, that seems quite likely.

Comment: @DavidWallace This took some time to understand. Thank you Axel for EOF statement. Now I understand why the values would not process after the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this code:

```
while (in.read()!= -1);
seller = in.readLine();
price = Double.parseDouble(in.readLine());
in.close();
```

The first line reads everything from the reader, without doing anything with what it reads. Then, when everything has been read, you're trying to read a line again. That will obviously return null, since you've already read everything. And then you're trying to read a line again (which of course continues to return null), and parse this null to a double.

And at the end, you close the reader, but since you don't do it in a finally block, the NPE that is thrown before prevents it to be closed.

I think it's time for you to read the javadoc of the methods you're using, and the Java IO tutorial.

Also, avoid this like the plague:

```
catch (IOException e) {}
```

You're simply hiding the exception from yourself, making any diagnostic impossible if an IOException occurs.

Comment: I will be honest. I did not even research on the "exception" part. I was concentrating on the upper portion of grabbing the values from the ext file. In the future, I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between compile errors and runtime errors (which this is).

try this instead of the while loop

```
String line = in.readLine();
if(line != null) {
    seller = line;
}
line = in.readLine();
if(line != null) {
    price = Double.parseDouble(line);
}
in.close();
```